# recursively checking data containing other data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have to solve a problem. I have a set of data of the following structure, and have to create an array of all bags containing a shiny gold bag (including bags that contain bags containing the shiny gold bag)

I have implemented something like the following, that works for the above dataset but not for the larger one(almost 600 lines). My question is:
-why the code is working for that small data set but not for the larger one
-I know that mine is not the most elegant way to solve it, so is that any technique to solve it more efficiently?

this is my code

```js
const input = `light red bags contain 1 bright white bag, 2 muted yellow bags.
    dark orange bags contain 3 bright white bags, 4 muted yellow bags.
    bright white bags contain 1 shiny gold bag.
    muted yellow bags contain 2 shiny gold bags, 9 faded blue bags.
    shiny gold bags contain 1 dark olive bag, 2 vibrant plum bags.
    dark olive bags contain 3 faded blue bags, 4 dotted black bags.
    vibrant plum bags contain 5 faded blue bags, 6 dotted black bags.
    faded blue bags contain no other bags.
    dotted black bags contain no other bags.`
  .split("\n")
  .map((row) => Array(row))
  .map((row) => row[0].replace("contain", ",").split(","));

function checkColors(arr, str) {
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].includes(str)) return arr[0];
  }
}

let colors = input
  .map((entry) => checkColors(entry, "shiny gold"))
  .filter((entry) => entry != undefined)
  .map((entry) => entry.replace("bags", "").trim());

let colorsMain = colors;

let tempCol = [];
do {
  for (let j = 0; j < colors.length; j++) {
    tempCol = input.map((entry) => checkColors(entry, colors[j]));
  }
  tempCol = tempCol
    .filter((entry) => entry != undefined)
    .map((entry) => entry.replace("bags", "").trim());

  colorsMain = colorsMain.concat(tempCol);
  colors = tempCol;
  console.log(colorsMain);
} while (tempCol.length > 0);

console.log(colorsMain.length);
```

Comment: In what way does the program fail for bigger numbers? Are you running out of memory?

Comment: I made you a [mcve] - no need for the fs part to answer the issue

Comment: Does not work in what way? Iff I take your script and repeat the lines 600 times, the script still runs

Comment: You are most likely running out of memory. Keep in mind that the blow up of bags is exponential. You should store the number of bags in each category rather than store each separately to save memory.

Comment: no, I do no get any error for out of memory, just a wrong colorsMain array (it should be 300 element length, but my code gives me only 10 element length)

Answer (score 0):

You could build an object with all relations and then collect the wanted values.

```js
const
    addToSet = (s, v) => (relations[v] || []).reduce(addToSet, s.add(v)),
    data = `light red bags contain 1 bright white bag, 2 muted yellow bags.
dark orange bags contain 3 bright white bags, 4 muted yellow bags.
bright white bags contain 1 shiny gold bag.
muted yellow bags contain 2 shiny gold bags, 9 faded blue bags.
shiny gold bags contain 1 dark olive bag, 2 vibrant plum bags.
dark olive bags contain 3 faded blue bags, 4 dotted black bags.
vibrant plum bags contain 5 faded blue bags, 6 dotted black bags.
faded blue bags contain no other bags.
dotted black bags contain no other bags.`,
    relations = data
        .split(/[\r\n]+/)
        .reduce((r, s) => {
            const
                [value, key] = s.split(' bags contain '),
                keys = key === 'no other bags.'
                    ? []
                    : key
                        .split(/[,.]\s*/)
                        .filter(Boolean)
                        .map(s => s.match(/\d+\s(.*)\sbag/)[1]);

            keys.forEach(k => (r[k] ??= []).push(value));
            return r;
        }, {}),
    result = [...relations['shiny gold'].reduce(addToSet, new Set)];

console.log(result);
console.log(relations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: mmm. however the result array is not correct because "dark olive" and "vibrant plum" do not contain bags containing the target bag :( . I need only bags containing the target or bags containing bags containing the target. Bags contained by the target are not included. So the result array should contain the light red and dark orange bags, together with the bright white and muted yellow ones

Comment: forgive me, but I am still quite new...may I ask the meaning of the commas (instead of the semicolon, I am used to), for example at the end of the addToSet function and after the declaration of the data?

Comment: it is a list of declarations and initialization, separated by comma of [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), like `const name = value, name1 = value1, name2 = value2;` the semicolon ends the statement.

Comment: that's correct. I didn't notice the there was just one const that was applying to different variables. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```js
const input = `light red bags contain 1 bright white bag, 2 muted yellow bags.
    dark orange bags contain 3 bright white bags, 4 muted yellow bags.
    bright white bags contain 1 shiny gold bag.
    muted yellow bags contain 2 shiny gold bags, 9 faded blue bags.
    shiny gold bags contain 1 dark olive bag, 2 vibrant plum bags.
    dark olive bags contain 3 faded blue bags, 4 dotted black bags.
    vibrant plum bags contain 5 faded blue bags, 6 dotted black bags.
    faded blue bags contain no other bags.
    dotted black bags contain no other bags.`

function buildColorDict(input) {
  const colorDict = {}
  input.split("\n").map((line) => {
    return line.match(/([a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+)+(?=\s+bags?)/g)
  }).forEach((arr) => {
    arr.slice(1).forEach((color) => {
      colorDict[color] ? colorDict[color].push(arr[0]) : colorDict[color] = [arr[0]]
    })
  })
  return colorDict
}

function lookUp(colorDict, color) {
  const _lookUp = (_color) => {
    if (colorDict[_color]) {
      return colorDict[_color].concat(colorDict[_color].map((_color1)=> _lookUp(_color1)).flat())
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
  return new Set(_lookUp(color))
}

const colorDict = buildColorDict(input)
const result = lookUp(colorDict, "shiny gold")

console.log(Array.from(result))
```

Basically, extract color from the `input` using `regex`, and build a reverse look up dictionary. Given a color, let's say `shiny gold`. It looks up which bag contains it, and using the colors found to look up which bags contain the found colored bags in a recursive way.

Comment: what is a reverse look up dictionary?

Comment: Basically, it's just a plain javascript object. You can `console.log(colorDict)` to check its structure.